# How bind List to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have written a class that have a method in website that bind List of Entity objects of my database to DropDownList Like this:

```
 internal static void bind(List<Book> list, DropDownList ddl)
 {
   try
   {
           ddl.Items.Clear();
           ddl.Items.Add(li);// li is an ListItem Like -> ListItem("Please                    Select","");
           ddl.DataSource = list;
           ddl.DataBind();
   }
   catch (Exception)
    { }
```

}

when i want to bind another object like List or ... I must write another method with Just difference in Lists .
Is there any way to write One method to bind all my List in my asp.net Sit and evry time i will want  i could bind that in another page?

Comment: another object like List or..? Whats your question?

Comment: Do you mean to have a generic method to bind a set of dropdown lists at once go?

Comment: I want use One method ,in this practice (way) i have to write one method for evry Generic list and this means i muse write many method.

Comment: Plenty of DropDown binding techniques to various data structures are described in: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214418/Binding-DropDownList-to-various-data-structures . You can convert List to array, or use Dictionary instead (recommended). Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

## 1. Use `IEnumerable` as the parameter type

This allows you to accept Lists as well as other enumerable types. I would recommend this unless you need to only accept lists for some reason.

```
internal static void bind(IEnumerable list, DropDownList ddl)
{
    try
    {
        ddl.Items.Clear();
        ddl.Items.Add(li);
        ddl.DataSource = list;
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

## 2. Use a generic method.

```
internal static void bind<T>(List<T> list, DropDownList ddl)
{
    try
    {
        ddl.Items.Clear();
        ddl.Items.Add(li);
        ddl.DataSource = list;
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```